# Constant Reference to Non-Const Object

Tags: c++, reference

Finding it difficult to wrap my head around why I can't have an immutable reference to a mutable object? If I pass a reference to a container like so:

```
auto f(const map<int, int>& x) -> decltype(non-const map iterator) {...}
```

It considers `x` to be const and any iterators I request of it are of the `const_iterator` type.

I want the following (or so I thought):
`auto f(map<int, int>& const x) -> decltype(non-const map iterator)`
But it does not compile.

This will not be hard to work around, but I was hoping for some uniformity in my project's code-base regarding const.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "const reference". References have no mutable structure.

Comment: The reference is already immutable, you cannot make it refer to another variable. You have a reference to a `const` object, which is why you're getting `const_iterator`. Why can't you pass it by reference to get your desired behaviour like you propose in the second code example?

Comment: Your question is mistitled (asking for the opposite of what you say you want).    You are trying to obtain a non-`const` reference from a `const` container.   Why do you want an iterator that can be used to change elements of a `const` container?

Comment: Primarily I was hoping to make the syntax clear when calling the function.  Was hoping to call `f(map_01)` and guarantee to the user (me) that `map_01` isn't changed.  Without the `const` qualifier, I can still pass by reference, but what guaruntees do I get (outside of me being the author) that function `f` won't modify `map_01`?

Comment: Your first example allows the compiler to enforce immutability on the map parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you can't, in any reliable way, get an `iterator` out of a `const` std container.

To illustrate why that is, take a look at how containers are implemented.

```
template<typename T>
class map
{
    struct node {
        T data;
        node *lchild, *rchild, *parent;
    };
public:
    iterator begin();
    const_iterator begin() const;
private:
    node* head;
};
```

Containers, due to their nature, needs to treat constness in an indirect way. They typically hold a pointer to memory that holds the objects, qualifying a container with `const` only affects the pointer and its methods.

```
// const map looks like
node* const head;
```

If containers were to naively return an `iterator` even when it is qualified with `const`, the compiler won't complain, you didn't syntactically mutate anything in the container after all.

```
// this is legal but wrong in a const map
head->data = T{};

// constness only prevents this
head = nullptr;
```

However since a container is conceptually the pointer *and* the stuff pointed to by the pointer, returning a `iterator` when qualified with `const` is semantically wrong. To remedy that, we introduce the `const` overloads, guaranteeing that a `const` container will truly be `const`.

As far as the `map` is concerned, giving out an `iterator` instantly breaks the contract that `const` should afford. There is no way the `map` can ensure its constness after it gives out an `iterator`, you may or may not mutate the contents with it.